# why G1 Garbage Collector use single thread in full garbage collections?

Tags: java, multithreading, garbage-collection

Today,I have read the g1 document here [oracle g1 colletor document](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/tutorials/tutorials-1876574.html)

which said that "Full garbage collections are still single threaded, but if tuned properly your applications should avoid full GCs."

I cannot understand why g1 can't use multi-thread in full gc.

Anyone can give me an explaination! thanks

Comment: Lets turn this around: what do you know about G1 garbage collection in detail; and what makes you think that *full* GC can run in parallel? It would make **much** more sense if *you* explained your thinking, instead of leaving *all* that work to others!

Answer (score 2):

Simply because that has not been implemented. GCs are complex beasts, so implementations don't come for free. And it is not a priority since full GCs are really a *should not happen* thing with G1. That said, it may eventually according to [openjdk bug 8172890](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8172890)